# Why is fwrite() writing `#!/usr/bin/env php` to my output file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been exploring how to create a downloadable file on my WP plugin page. I've got as far as creating a text file and outputting the string `'Hello?'` to it. This happens in the `download()` method.

It almost works as expected but the downloaded file contains the following line: `#!/usr/bin/env php`. Why? What do I need to do to prevent that from being written to the file?

The downloaded file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
Hello?
```

This is the plugin page's controller:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || die();

class helloSettingsPageController {

    private static $settings_page;

    // scripts,
    public static function init() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( __CLASS__, 'add_menu' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'load_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_action_hello_download', array( __CLASS__,'download') );
    }

    // setup
    public static function add_menu() {
        self::$settings_page = add_menu_page( 'hello', 'hello', 'edit_pages', 'hello', array( __CLASS__, 'render_page' ), false, 62 );
    }

    public static function load_scripts( $hook ) {
        if ( self::$settings_page !== $hook ) {
            return;
        }

        $path = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/hello-script.js';
        wp_enqueue_script( 'hello-script', $path, array( 'jquery' ) );
    }

    // view
    public static function render_page() {
        $html = ( 'html/settings_page.html' );
        include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../' . $html;
    }


    // actions
    public static function download() {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_pages')) { wp_die('Permission denied'); }
        $retrieved_nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], 'admin_action_hello_download') ) {
            wp_die('Nonce verification failed!');
        }

        header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.txt"' );

        $outstream = fopen( "php://output", 'w' );

        fwrite( $outstream, "Hello?");
        fclose( $outstream );

        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's nothing to do with the sample code in my question.

I tracked it down to psysh. The hashbang disappears when I removed the psysh include. The problem is documented on github: [psysh prints the php hashbang when used as library](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/320).